# Создание списков и словарей

Tags: python, словари, список

Здравствуйте!

У меня есть список, состоящий из, допустим, 5000 элементов. Создал я его с помощью цикла for или генератора списка. После заполнения значениями я могу обращаться к любому из них, но как сделать, чтобы не запускать скрипт каждый раз и заполнять список, а записать его один раз и потом либо дополнять, либо править и чтобы была возможность импорта в другие модули? Потому что запуская скрипт, создавая список из n-го количества элементов - это очень долго.
Может, в таком случае необходимо пользоваться базами данных? Прошу прощения, если неясно объяснил суть вопроса. :)

Comment: Смотрите [ответ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/899103/python-write-a-list-to-a-file) с pickle.

Comment: Можно и базой данных, можно список в файл скидывать после создания и потом брать оттуда из любого модуля... 5к записей будут читаться очень быстро.

Зависит от потребностей

Comment: Спасибо, модуль pickle хорошо подходит для моих задач. ) Я так понимаю, его можно использовать и со словарями и потом дополнять записи, переводя запись на конец файла?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если создавать список из 5000 (маленькое число) элементов слишком долго при старте программы, то можно попробовать оптимизировать её производительность или считывать уже посчитанные данные с диска, сети и т.д., если это занимает приемлемое время, или просто держать программу всё время запущенной (почему нет).

Можно использовать разные форматы для сохранения:

- json -- простой человеко, машино-читаемый формат, понимаемый многими языками;
- sqlite3 -- реляционная база данных в одном файле;
- pickle -- удобный, поддерживает многие Питон-объекты, как есть, что может приводить к проблемам с разными версиями программы (если классы поменялись). Непереносим и небезопасен (может привести к исполнению произвольного кода);
- shelve -- как словарь, но на диске (использует pickle внутри).

> чтобы была возможность импорта в другие модули

Можно просто объект глобальный импортировать (сам список или прокси, с определённым интерфейсом, например, чтобы запретить модификацию другими модулями):

```
from source_module import your_list_proxy

item = your_list_proxy[index]
```

> Подскажите еще, пожалуйста, а возможно ли списки записывать в таблицы postresql?

@Piroru: возможно. Существует несколько способов, например, каждый элемент списка в свою строку в таблице (или даже несколько таблиц) или весь список как одна json колонка.  Какой вариант выбрать, заслуживает отдельного вопроса (ещё вопрос, какую ORM использовать или использовать ли вообще). Что может помочь ответить на вопрос: что за список, какие операции с ним необходимо производить, как часто, какие требования к производительности, переносимости на разные системы, возможности по установке Питон-пакетов с Pypi.

Comment: Подскажите еще, пожалуйста, а возможно ли списки записывать в таблицы postresql? Если возможно, дайте ссылку на статью толковую.

Comment: Список состоит из id-ов, вытащенных с помощью facebook API, далее из этого списка формируются словари(их по хорошему тоже надо записывать в бд), словари состоят в основном из ключа(id) и текста статьи(значения). После записи в бд планируется сделать связи между таблицами типа один-ко-многим, и с помощью запросов по id доставать остальную информацию связанную со статьей(сообщения, лайки и пр.). Операции будут производиться раз в месяц(будут пополняться и доставаться), производительность большой роли не играет, переносимость на другие системы тоже, возможности по установке пакетов есть.

Comment: @Piroru: учитывая либеральные требования, можно использовать первое самое простое, что работает и быть готовым переписывать раз в месяц (менять схему db, библиотеки, используемые для работы) по потребности. В данном случае можно стремится к [нормализованной db](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0), чтобы уменьшить вероятность некоторых классов ошибок. Статьи будет мало почитать, нужно почитать в объёме книги (большинство потом забудется и станет просто "здравым смыслом").

Comment: Спасибо, буду разбираться с данной темой. )